# meaning of 'two-fifties'

Tags: meaning

what does 'two-fifties' meaning?

"You know the drill— two-fifties, two-fifties, two-fifties. Stop-and-frisk ‘til we get this guy."

I listen to this talk from a detective on the TV drama 'Law & Order'.

I can't find it on a dictionary or Google. Please help me!

Comment: Various online sources assert that "250" is New York Police Department slang for "stop and frisk."

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the sentence is referencing “250”, which is an NYPD code for the stop and frisk law— the right to stop, question and pat down anyone deemed reasonably suspicious. The beginning of the sentence and the repetition of the code incidates that this is something they do often.